# Area of circle segment

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Why does it take so much time computing a simple area of segment of a circle radius $a,$ width $h<a?$

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x ( 2 a - x)], {x, 0, h}]
```

Would it improve to define this Region? Is symbolic computation  time-consuming? What is a work-around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes *Mathematica* needs a decent amount of tweaking.

```
$Assumptions = 0 < h < a && h ∈ Reals;
Integrate[Sqrt[x (2 a - x)], {x, 0, h}] (*Gives seemingly complex result*)
ComplexExpand[%, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify (*Gives real result*)
% /. {a -> 2, h -> 1.}
```

> ```
> (1/2)*((-a)*Sqrt[(2*a - h)*h] + Sqrt[(2*a - h)*h^3] + a^2*Pi - I*a^2*(Log[2] + Log[a] - 2*Log[I*Sqrt[2*a - h] + Sqrt[h]]))
>
> (1/2)*((-a)*Sqrt[(2*a - h)*h] + Sqrt[(2*a - h)*h^3] + a^2*Pi - 2*a^2*ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + (2*a)/h]])
> ```
>
> 1.22837

### Original Answer

Just got to give it a little more information about `h`.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x (2 a - x)], {x, 0, h}, Assumptions -> 0 < h < a && h ∈ Reals]
```

> (-a Sqrt[(2 a - h) h] + Sqrt[(2 a - h) h^3] + a^2 π - 
>     I a^2 (Log[2] + Log[a] - 2 Log[I Sqrt[2 a - h] + Sqrt[h]]))

Comment: But $ I = \sqrt{-1}$ still hangs on.

Comment: @ That Gravity Guy Thanks for tweak. It helped.

Comment: @ That Gravity Guy Would you care to model 3-body problem ( or special  case M1,M2 >> m), with L1,l2 etc.?